# SQL/Oracle Function to find out how far data goes back in a database

Tags: oracle

Looking to find out a date, one result in the form of a date, that can tell me how far back data goes in the database.

I tried Select

```
     Min('2001-03-15') From  prdedwvwh.prescription_fill_sold
```

but this did not work

Comment: Use name of a column instead of  `'2001-03-15'`

Answer (score 0):

```
select Min(t.YourDateColumn) from prdedwvwh.prescription_fill_sold t
```

Would work fine